# How to fix the "keyboard setting" not opening

Tags: kali-linux, keyboard, gnome-shell, settings

Here's my system info from uname -a:

```
Linux fu457 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

GNOME Shell 3.21.91

Now, when I go to 'Settings' and click on 'Keyboard' to add a custom shortcut key, the 'Keyboard' setting window will not open. It will flash a second or two in the taskbar (topbar) and exit immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the current work around for this is to upgrade to libgtk-3.0 from debian unstable. According to the bug tracker this should be added to the repos on 9/16. Although I just did a dist-upgrade and the problem still persists.

Here is the bug tracker https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3579

Comment: Thanks. Does the upgrade to libgtk-3.0 from debian unstable work? I'm gonna try that now.

Comment: Well, I tried it out and it seems to let you adjust keyboard shortcuts, but a lot of the other functionality is now missing. It's an improvement.

Comment: apt search libgtk-3.0
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
libgtk-3-0/kali-rolling,now 3.21.5-3 amd64 [installed]
GTK+ graphical user interface library
libgtk-3-0-dbg/kali-rolling,now 3.21.5-3 amd64 [installed]
GTK+ libraries and debugging symbols

I have the above packages and versions installed. Not sure if it's the right one but it doesn't seem to fix the issue for me. Any other options I can try? Or did I install the wrong packages?